# system theme won't apply to program

Tags: gtk, themes, vala

I'm training in Vala and everything was going ok until I applied a pkexec executable, now my system theme(dark) won't apply to the app

Here's my code:

```
public class Thinkfan : Gtk.Application {

    public Thinkfan() {
        Object (
              application_id: "com.github.isa-pp.thinkfan-control-gui",
              flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        );
    }
    
    protected override void activate() {
        settings();
        build_window();
    }

    private void build_window () {
        var window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(this);
        window.title = "Thinkfan Control";
        window.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        window.set_default_size (280,113);
        window.show_all ();
    }
    private void settings (){
        var granite_settings = Granite.Settings.get_default ();
        var gtk_settings = Gtk.Settings.get_default ();
        gtk_settings.gtk_application_prefer_dark_theme = granite_settings.prefers_color_scheme == Granite.Settings.ColorScheme.DARK;

        granite_settings.notify["prefers-color-scheme"].connect (() => {
            gtk_settings.gtk_application_prefer_dark_theme = granite_settings.prefers_color_scheme == Granite.Settings.ColorScheme.DARK;
        });
    }

    public static int main(string[] args) {
        var thinkfan = new Thinkfan();
        return thinkfan.run(args);
    }
  
}
```

and my pkexec is pretty simple, just

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/home/azure/thinkfan-vala/thinkfan"
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to run a UI application with root privileges? The sensor and control programs I have seen usually split their code into a daemon and a UI client.

Comment: @jens-mühlenhoff I'm trying things, I might do that in the end, not sure yet. But I really don't see any problems in running the UI as root

Comment: Themes only apply to one user. If you didn't change the theme for the root account, it will be the default one (E.g. Adwaita)